# Array of WinForm Elements

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, combobox, textbox

So I do have a WinForm in my Programm, which contains a series of each a ComboBox and two TextBoxs. There are atm 8 Lines, but this will increase to a total of at least 32, therefore I would like to work with an Array or similar. How do I do that?

My current working, method is that a create a new array of TextBoxes/ComboBoxes which I assign the designated Elemt of the WinForm, manually. Therefore I have a list like this:

```
tbGU[0] = tbGU1;
tbGO[0] = tbGO1;
cbS[0] = cbS1;
```

Of course, this looks awful and isn't great if it's copied many times. Anyone got a Solution to my Problem?

I need to access the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox and the Text of the TextBoxes.
I was hoping that I could avoid having to create all the Elements manually by code.

Comment: Have you thought about putting the three controls (ComboBox, 2xTextBox) in to a Custom Control. You would have 1/3rd of the total number of controls to deal with then

Comment: Did you considered of using `DataGridView` control, where you can dynamically create multiple controls?

Comment: You can always use `List<T>` and initialize in one go: `List<ComboBox> cBoxes = new List<ComboBox>() {cbS1, cbS12, cbS3...};` You access it just like an array.

Comment: As written below, can't have them in an evenly destributed manner, because they are located around/ on a graphic, so a DataGridView is not "acceptable" for my application. Gonna go with the shortend Versionen either by using a List or the new[] (fancy the later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use the array initializer syntax:

```
ComboBox[] cbS = new[] { cbS1, cbS2, cbS3 ... };
```

Another way of doing this would be to get rid of the variables `cbS1`, `cbS2` ... `cBSn` altogether and create the controls in a for loop.

```
ComboxBox[] cbS = new ComboBox[32];
// declare the text box arrays here as well
for (int i = 0 ; i < cbS.Length ; i++) {
    cbS[i] = new ComboBox();
    cbS[i].Location = ... // use "i" to help you position the control
    // configure your combo box ...
    this.Controls.Add(cbS[i]);

    // do the same for the text boxes.
}
```

A third way is to create a custom control:

```
// name this properly!
public class MyControl: UserControl {
    public ComboBox CbS { get; }
    public TextBox TbGU { get; }
    public TextBox TbGO { get; }

    public MyControl() {
        // create and configure the combo box and text boxes here ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use a for loop to create lots of `MyControl`s.

Comment: Unfortunatly, they are not evenly destributed on my frame (e.g. using a sort of self made CardLayout similar to the java one, and even there they are set according to a graphic , so there is no "rule" to how it is set the Elements.
Probably going to stick with my method, but change it to the shorter version of yours.

Comment: @Martin But the Combo boxes and text boxes corresponds to each other right? If they are related, then you should create a custom control.

Comment: Well, maybe your right and I should use them, I'm considering it atm. To clarify, I do select an sensor at the combobox, which I have to set two critical values for (for the further process) You also choose the position of the sensor which is marked using the index of the element (It is a rather complex measuring system I have to control with the application, hence the !>32 sensors xD). Though I'm already glad that I at least was able to minimise the (minimum) of 96 Lines to 3, (very bulky) lines. Thanks for that